# I am trying to connect my flutter app with firebase but it doesn't generate the file named "Generated_plugins_registrant.dart"

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to connect my flutter app with firebase but it doesn't generate the file named "Generated_plugins_registrant.dart", I don't if this has happened to anyone else, and I am using Mac (Idk if using mac is reason). I have added every dependencies and plugins required and I have done everything I can but the file just won't generate.

Answer (score 0):

When I first set up my projects I used the [flutterfire cli](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli/) and it automatically generated what was needed. Hope this helps

Comment: nope, didn't generate the file